# Segmentation Fault (11) on client webpage. 99% of the time it is limited only to Chrome

Tags: linux, apache, google-chrome

Hoping some SysAdmins can weigh in here, because I am most assuredly not one.

**OS:** Ubuntu Server 14.04

**CMS:** Expression Engine 2.9 (with extras, such as Expresso Store)

**Server type:** Virtual

**Error:** Segmentation fault (11)

```
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

We do not believe it is a code issue on the ExpressionEngine side of things, and my research indicates it is normally something awry on the server itself or externally (browser, ISP, etc). Issue is, no matter where in the country one accesses this particular page on the site it will routinely fail, specifically in Chrome.

The client cannot launch the site in its present state so we have been scrambling to find an issue.

While playing detective certain facts became known to me.

The virtual server is owned by the client themselves and the physical boxes are located at their facility. Their lead IT professional, who has absolutely no real experience with Linux, has been maintaining the box and the OS. This last point is critical, because he has been updating any and everything on the server the second it appears on the list. They have indicated that, for them, this is normal procedure for their Windows servers.

This set off a few alarm bells.

The IT professional has been doing this for many weeks without us knowing, and the error started happening on the 5th of September. This coincided with two updates made by him, one of which was **ligbcrypt11 amd64 1.5.3-2ubuntu4.1** . This has remained unchanged since September 5th.

Could this be causing the issue? Does anybody know of any problems afflicting specifically Chrome regarding the server sending no data?

An aside: I have attempted to use GDP to backtrace the problem, but I cannot get Apache to actually generate an error file out in the folder located in /tmp that I created. When I look at the logs it does say that a dump file could be located there, so the code I placed in apache2.conf is clearly working. Permissions and ownership have been set for the folder.

I made the following changes to try and get it to work:

```
etc/apache2.conf   (file location)

CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump   (code added)


/etc/sysctl.conf   (file location)

kernel.core_uses_pid = 1        (code added)
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp   (code added)
fs.suid_dumpable = 2              (code added)
```

There are so many things that could be happening that I just don't know where to start with this. This isn't my area of expertise.